# iOS change view controller from the app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

Above is the storyboard for my chat app.
What you'r not seeing to the left before the `Navigation Controller` is a simple login view. The Storyboard Segue identifier to the `Navigation Controller` is `mainViewC`.

What i want to do is to take the user to the `Conv View Controller` when a `push notification` is pressed.

This is what i've got so far:

```
// AppDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) ConvViewController *convViewController;

// AppDelegate.m
self.window.rootViewController = self.convViewController;
```

This takes me to the correct view but the view is black. Im guessing this has something to do with the `Navigiation Controller` not being loaded correctly..

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to reset the root vc?

Comment: I just want to take the users to the `Conv View Controller`

Answer (score 4):

What you'll need to do is access the view controller from the story board. First go to the VC you wish to bring users to and give it a Storyboard ID. Then in your app delegate you would write.

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```